# How does bash expand escaped characters when dereferencing variables

Tags: regex, bash, sed, dereference

If I quit using variables, and just write the regexes directly into to the last sed command, 
everything works. But as it is here, no substitutions are done?

```
#!/bin/bash
#html substitutions
ampP="\&amp;"
ampR="&"

ltP="\&lt;"
ltR="<"

gtP="\&gt;"
gtR=">"

quotP="\&quot;"
quotP2='\&#8220;'
quotP3="\&#8221;"
quotR="\""

tripDotP="\&#8230"
tripDotR="..."

tickP="\&#8217;"
tickR="\´"

#get a random page, and filter out the quotes
#pick a random quote
#translate wierd html symbols
curl "www.yodaquotes.net/page/$((RANDOM % 9 +1))/" -Ls | sed -nr 's/.*data-text=\"([^\"]+)\".*/\1/p' \
| sort -R | head -n1 \
| sed 's/"$ampP"/"$ampR"/g; s/$ltP/$ltR/g; s/$gtP/$gtR/g; s/$quotP/$quotR/g; s/"$quotP2"/"$quotR"/g; s/$quotP3/$quotR/g; s/$tripDotP/$tripDotR/g; s/$stickP/$stickR/g'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sed isn't going to work:

```
sed 's/"$ampP"/"$ampR"/g'
```

because of wrong shell quoting. Your shell variables won't be expanded at all in single quotes. Try using this form:

```
sed "s~$ampP~$ampR~g"
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that.. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Debugging 101: Let's just `echo` what sed receives:

```
echo 's/"$ampP"/"$ampR"/g; s/$ltP/$ltR/g; s/$gtP/$gtR/g; s/$quotP/$quotR/g; s/"$quotP2"/"$quotR"/g; s/$quotP3/$quotR/g; s/$tripDotP/$tripDotR/g; s/$stickP/$stickR/g'

s/"$ampP"/"$ampR"/g; s/$ltP/$ltR/g; s/$gtP/$gtR/g; s/$quotP/$quotR/g; s/"$quotP2"/"$quotR"/g; s/$quotP3/$quotR/g; s/$tripDotP/$tripDotR/g; s/$stickP/$stickR/g
```

That doesn't look right now, does it?

There's **no** variable substitution within single quotes in bash. That's why we have two different quotes, so you can decide which one is more appropriate for the task.

For readability I would suggest putting each sed command within double quotes.

Like this: `"s/$ampP/$ampR/g"`

Comment: Actually, the "many scripts in one arguments" works perfectly.

Comment: Putting every expression in quotes doesn't work for me.
It might with an "-e" for every expression too though
Any tips on splitting it to multiple lines?

Comment: you can put every -e in new line. I found that a lot more readable:

 -e "expr" \
 -e "expr" \
 ...